# ASP.NET Assembly -IL to Source

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

Ofcourse the IL is lanuage independent,can i get the source code back from IL (let the source code be any language C#,VB) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and [Denis Bauer's Reflector.FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx):

> The Reflector.FileDisassembler is a
>   little add-in for the new version of
>   Lutz Roeder's .NET Reflector that you
>   can use to dump the decompiler output
>   to files of any Reflector supported
>   language (C#, VB.NET, Delphi). This is
>   extremely useful if you are searching
>   for a specific line of code as you can
>   use VS.NET's "Find in Files" or want
>   to convert a class from one language
>   to another.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to an extent, http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/.

Answer (score 1):

Use

[MSIL Disassembler (Ildasm.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can using ILDASM.exe

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28VS.80%29.aspx